# json array listview in blackberry cascades

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

1.Array Type

```
{"DATA":
[
{"CategoryID":"3","CategoryName":"News","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
{"CategoryID":"4","CategoryName":"Daily Paper","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
{"CategoryID":"5","CategoryName":"Thanthi","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
{"CategoryID":"1","CategoryName":"Newspaper","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
{"CategoryID":"2","CategoryName":"Magazine","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"}
]
}
```

---

2.Direct Type

```
[
{"CategoryID":"3","CategoryName":"News","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
{"CategoryID":"4","CategoryName":"Daily Paper","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
{"CategoryID":"5","CategoryName":"Thanthi","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
{"CategoryID":"1","CategoryName":"Newspaper","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
{"CategoryID":"2","CategoryName":"Magazine","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"}
]
```

for direct type declaration --->

```
 ListItemComponent {
     type: "listItem"
     StandardListItem {
         title: ListItemData.CategoryName
     }
 }
```

---

my question is how to declare **title: ListItemData.???????**  for first json array model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ListItemComponent {
 type: "listItem"
 StandardListItem {
 title: ListItemData.DATA[0].CategoryName
 }
 }
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me. I even tried changing `listItem` to `item` and few other changes, but none of them worked. It don't even shows the **ListView**